# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation in progress, on php artisan queue:work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.8, mysql-8.0, php-7.3

I am using mysql 8, `php artisan queue:work` fail every 31 secs with this error trace below.
From what I see, this happens when it wants to process next queued job (#17), then try to create a transaction on trace #21 but fail to create a pdo connection with mysql driver.

Anyone can help me why this is happening? any tips or a way to debug this thankss in advance!

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation in progress
#29 /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(27): PDO::__construct
#28 /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(27): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::__construct
#27 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(67): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createPdoConnection
#26 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(46): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createConnection
#25 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector::connect
#24 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(182): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}
#23 [internal](0): call_user_func
#22 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(916): Illuminate\Database\Connection::getPdo
#21 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(109): Illuminate\Database\Connection::createTransaction
#20 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(93): Illuminate\Database\Connection::beginTransaction
#19 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Connection::transaction
#18 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(204): Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue::pop
#17 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(247): Illuminate\Queue\Worker::getNextJob
#16 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(107): Illuminate\Queue\Worker::daemon
#15 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand::runWorker
#14 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand::handle
#13 [internal](0): call_user_func_array
#12 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}
#11 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod
#10 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call
#9 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(572): Illuminate\Container\Container::call
#8 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Console\Command::execute
#7 /vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run
#6 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Illuminate\Console\Command::run
#5 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(934): Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand
#4 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun
#3 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run
#2 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(89): Illuminate\Console\Application::run
#1 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle
#0 /artisan(37): null
```

Comment: this is because another service that use the same mysql open the connection and didnt close it, so it affected my service

Comment: how exactly you fixed this?

Comment: Sonu Bamniya - Because there are someone who code to open mysql connection and didnt close it, it caused that error, so the fix is when you done using the connection please close the mysql connection

Comment: hi @Calvin, was wondering if you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: maybe there is connection that is open?

Comment: @Calvin hmmm I think queue:work should open a new PDO connection everytime and there is no connection reuse here

Comment: From what I remember... mine was because connection is full because other program is using connection without closing it, so when queue:work need to use it, there isnt available. Maybe try to monitor mysql connection usage.